# Nīlakaṇṭha Dhāraṇī (“Great Compassion Mantra”) One of the most popular Mantra in China

Tags: doubt

**Ques 1) Base on Wiki below, which English translation found to be accurate? D.T. Suzuki or Kazuaki Tanahashi and Joan Halifax**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%ABlaka%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%ADha_Dh%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87%C4%AB

**Ques 2) Refer to some Buddhism Documentaries, Theravada Buddhism disallow reciting of Mantra. Does it a truth?**

Personally i found this Mantra translated into positive self-talk which physiologically helping on self healing of decease. i.e. Having better peace of mind simply can cure most of the deceases?
https://www.wikihow.com/Think-Positively-About-Yourself

It has content of worshiping too so the person too focus on it without understand the basic Buddhism could be lead to superstitious which is inappropriate. I found no issue combination of meditation and of course focus of practices must be Buddhism basic which is Four Noble of Truths.

Answer (score 1):

Most popular current philosophical movement in China is Falun Gong; they've been cracking down on it. The leader contacted me once... was quite insistent and sure he was "god" I've met another male calling himself god and once a female saying she was god too; the female also identified herself later also as the devil... Eh whatever nice to meet you now go take your medication like you're supposed too.

My favorite movement in China is Wing Chun; used to be a female only martial art then men got involved and it became Tai Chi... Same basic thing these days.

The best cure for Buddhism is just sitting; make sure sitting never stops and you'll be doing it right... breathing can stop, world can stop, everything can else stop... Just don't let sitting cease to be sitting. Before or After that Laying down and standing order doesn't matter.

There probably some wisdom or calmness to be found in what you posted... too many people shopping around chasing mind which is the inexhaustible 7th jhana it is the target audience of the poison arrow sutta... it hits the heart of the matter.

My advice to cure that is to go to one's original practice what got them started on whatever path... see it to the end. Make a firm resolve to do so same as Gotama: I'm gonna sit under this tree and see who dies or achieves enlightenment first.

Doubt however is good... always keep some doubt it builds humility otherwise you might start introducing yourself to other people as god.

Comment: This didnt exactly answering my question by the way. If you are talking about meditation then go to another post. If you would ask me, meditation is not suitable for beginner. if you search this stack, many side effects discussion - https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=meditation+side+effects

Comment: those monks when started, the first five years they're just focusing in basic precepts. Only after that they will practice meditation, it must have a strong reason behind right and applicable to lay Buddhist also right?

Comment: Lastly, For Mahayana, much changes and aligning to Theravada teaching i can notice in recent 10 years found on youtube especially those in South China. They would advise to focus in practice rather than worshiping, this version actually bought me into Buddhism.